# Can we have PK with a non unique index?

Tags: sql

Can we have PK with a non unique index?

Comment: It would be a contradictio in terminis. (It would contradict with its definition)

Comment: its just interview question.if we r creating table with non uniq column constraint based on that , can we create PK on that column  , after its possible to insert data in to that column on whioch basis. ?

Comment: Not a very hard one though :p

Comment: @ViralS.Patel, have you even not tried? Which dbms? (indexes are not included in the ANSI SQL standard...)

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is a unique identifier by definition, so it can never be non-unique. It might be possible to add a primary key to a column with a non-unique constraint provided there are no duplicates values for that column. It wouldn't make much sense though unless you are intending to replace the non-unique constraint with a primary key.

Comment: that wats the problem mahn , its possible to create PK with non uniq index column.. ?

Comment: No you can't create a PK with a non unique index column. However, you maybe able to add a primary key to a column with a non unique column constraint provided that column doesn't contain duplicates.